# Como evitar que o evento focusout dispare ao minimizar o navegador?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-eventos

Estou usando o evento focusout para chamar uma função quando o campo perder o foco. O problema é que quando eu minimizo a janela do browser, o evento dispara, pois parece perder o foco. O Mesmo ocorre, quando a função calcular_financeiro_parcela_movimento_calculos_padrao() efetua uma chamada ajax, pois parece que o foco se perde e o evento dispara.

Existe alguma forma de impedir que o evento focusout dispare nessas situações?

```
$('#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-valor-pago').focusout(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    calcular_financeiro_parcela_movimento_calculos_padrao();
});

function calcular_financeiro_parcela_movimento_calculos_padrao(tipoCalculo = FINANCEIRO_PARCELA_MOVIMENTO_CALCULOS_PADRAO_TIPO_CALCULAR_APENAS_PERCENTUAIS) {

    //startLoadGlobal(SPINNER_CALCULAR_VALOR_PARCELA);

    var financeiroParcelaId = $('#hid-financeiro-parcela-movimento-financeiro-parcela-id').val();

    var valorASerPago = $("#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-valor-a-ser-pago").val();
    var valorPago = $("#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-valor-pago").val();
    var valorTotal = $("#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-valor-total").val();
    var valorJuros = $('#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-valor-juros').val();
    var percentualJuros = $('#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-percentual-juros').val();
    var valorDesconto = $('#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-valor-desconto').val();
    var percentualDesconto = $('#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-percentual-desconto').val();
    var valorMulta = $('#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-valor-multa').val();
    var percentualMulta = $('#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-percentual-multa').val();
    var valorDesconto = $('#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-valor-desconto').val();

    var financeiroParcelaMovimentoCalculosPadraoViewModel = {
        FinanceiroParcelaId: financeiroParcelaId,
        FinanceiroParcelaMovimentoCalculosPadraoTipo: tipoCalculo,
        ValorASerPago: valorASerPago ? converterFormatoMoedaBrasileiraParaFormatoPadrao(valorASerPago) : 0,
        ValorTotal: valorTotal ? converterFormatoMoedaBrasileiraParaFormatoPadrao(valorTotal) : 0,
        ValorPago: valorPago ? converterFormatoMoedaBrasileiraParaFormatoPadrao(valorPago) : 0,
        ValorJuros: valorJuros ? converterFormatoMoedaBrasileiraParaFormatoPadrao(valorJuros) : 0,
        PercentualJuros: percentualJuros ? converterFormatoMoedaBrasileiraParaFormatoPadrao(percentualJuros) : 0,
        ValorMulta: valorMulta ? converterFormatoMoedaBrasileiraParaFormatoPadrao(valorMulta) : 0,
        PercentualMulta: percentualMulta ? converterFormatoMoedaBrasileiraParaFormatoPadrao(percentualMulta) : 0,
        ValorDesconto: valorDesconto ? converterFormatoMoedaBrasileiraParaFormatoPadrao(valorDesconto) : 0,
        PercentualDesconto: percentualDesconto ? converterFormatoMoedaBrasileiraParaFormatoPadrao(percentualDesconto) : 0
    };

    var dataParameter = $.param(financeiroParcelaMovimentoCalculosPadraoViewModel);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/financeiro-parcela-movimento-gerenciar/financeiro-parcela-movimento-calcular-valores-padrao",
        type: "GET",
        data: dataParameter,
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {

            stopLoadGlobal();

            if (typeof data.success !== 'undefined') {
                if (!data.success) {
                    swal("Oops", data.message, "error");

                    return false;
                }
            }

            $("#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-valor-a-ser-pago").val(data.financeiroParcelaMovimentoCalculosPadrao.valorASerPago.toLocaleString('pt-br', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }));
            $("#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-percentual-desconto").val(data.financeiroParcelaMovimentoCalculosPadrao.percentualDesconto.toLocaleString('pt-br', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }));
            $("#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-percentual-juros").val(data.financeiroParcelaMovimentoCalculosPadrao.percentualJuros.toLocaleString('pt-br', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }));
            $("#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-percentual-multa").val(data.financeiroParcelaMovimentoCalculosPadrao.percentualMulta.toLocaleString('pt-br', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }));
            $("#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-valor-total").val(data.financeiroParcelaMovimentoCalculosPadrao.valorTotal.toLocaleString('pt-br', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }));
            $("#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-valor-pago").val(data.financeiroParcelaMovimentoCalculosPadrao.valorPago.toLocaleString('pt-br', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }));
        },
        error: function () {
            stopLoadGlobal();
            alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Penso que a única forma de conseguir impedir este comportamento é utilizando uma flag de controlo. Veja o seguinte exemplo:

```js
let windowFocused = true;

$(window).blur(function(){
  windowFocused = false;
});

$(window).focus(function(){
  windowFocused = true;
});

$('#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-valor-pago').focusout(function(e) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!windowFocused) return;

    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Focus out ...');
  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-valor-pago" />
```

Comment: Não sei como agradecê-lo @dfvc. Funcionou corretamente :)